# What's Wrong With This Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have some text of which the following is a sample:

```
  2_Chief Ships.Niobe 2 0 2 1.0
  3_Chief Vehicles.WillisMB_US 1
[0_Chief_Road]
  77704.27 140254.33 120.00 0 2 9.166666984558105
  100653.84 140379.05 120.00
[2_Chief_Road]
  76911.77 139996.94 120.00 0 2 3.8583335876464844
  100446.47 140028.61 120.00
```

I want to retrieve this part under [0_Chief_Road]:

```
77704.27 140254.33 120.00 0 2 9.166666984558105
100653.84 140379.05 120.00
```

I'm using this code:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = null;
string routeTitle = "[0_Chief_Road]";  //  this is hard coded for StackOverflow
reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?<=" + routeTitle + @")[\d\.\s]+(?=\[)");
string routeText = reg.Match(chiefsSection).Captures[0].ToString();
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
4.27 140254.33 120.00 0 2 9.166666984558105
  100653.84 140379.05 120.00
```

...which is everything *after* the first zero! I've tried changing the values and it always returns everything after the first zero. I don't get why!!

Can anyone help out here?  Thank you!

Gregg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `routeTitle` contains brackets that, when used in a regular expression, will be interpreted as a character class. You need to escape any literal string before inserting it into a regular expression.

So you should use `string routeTitle = @"\[0_Chief_Road\]";`

Or use the `Regex.Escape()` function:

```
string routeTitle = "[0_Chief_Road]";  //  this is hard coded for StackOverflow
reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?<=" + Regex.Escape(routeTitle) + @")[\d\.\s]+(?=\[)");
```

Be aware that the CRLF after `[0_Chief_Road]` will also be part of the match - if you don't want that, add a `\s+` at the end of the lookbehind assertion.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks for waking me up!